# Stop automaticaly switching to 3g if wi-fi drops

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I have an android 2.2 phone.  The other day, I was using a wi-fi connection on my phone and had it tethered to my laptop.  For whatever reason, the wi-fi connection dropped and my phone starting using my phones 3g connection to continue the internet connection tethered to my laptop...

Is it possible to stop this from happening? i.e. if the wireless connection drops, don't use the 3g connection automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have no reason to why the wifi drops, you might try changing the wifi sleep policy. The wifi sleep policy handles when or if the wifi connection shall switch to mobile data. If this option is set to the default value, *When screen turns off*, wifi connection automatically switches off when the phone has been idle for a while. You can try setting this to *Never*, which will keep the connection on, even when the phone is not used.

To change this setting, navigate to **Settings** -> **Wireless & networks** -> **Wi-Fi settings** -> [Menu] -> **Advanced** -> **Wi-Fi sleep policy**.

Comment: What does `Never when plugged in` mean?

Comment: It means that the default policy (When screen turns off) is used when the device is on battery, and when the device is plugged into power Wi-Fi never go to sleep.

Comment: So if I have the phone plugged into a usb powered port, where the phone gets charged.  If I then enable wifi on the phone, and tethering to the laptop via the same usb port.  Will this work?  i.e. will wifi never turn off if I have the `never when plugged in` selected?  I'll give it a try asap anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think this will work! Give it a try!

Answer (score 5):

Turn off mobile data usage. Go to `Settings`->`Wireless and networks`->`Mobile network`(you should uncheck this). Some manufacturers may have a widget for this, such as HTC did for my Incredible(v1).

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling airplane mode. It will shut down all the radios on your device - cell, wifi, bluetooth. Then try explicitly turning the wifi back on. Not all devices support this - driver issues, I think - but in many you will wind up with the cell radio disabled and the wifi on.